# Linked XML to java code via id in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

How we can  linked XML to java code via id?
for example when we click on button we change the layer or give String from textView.

Comment: A lot more detail needs to be put into this question. One simple way to link XML to Java is by using a saxparser.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a DOM or SAX parser. A tutorial for DOM found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm) on how to read in XML and parse the individual elements. And a tutorial for SAX is found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html).

Here is an example SAX parser:
package ca.ubc.cs.recommender.bugzilla.parser;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

```
/**
 *     parse the XML information
 *     
 * @author whitecat
 *
 */
public class XMLParser extends DefaultHandler {

    // Remember information being parsed
    private StringBuffer accumulator;
    private StringBuffer xmlFile;

    public XMLParser(StringBuffer xmlFile) {
        this.xmlFile = xmlFile;
    }

    /**
     * Called at the start of the document (as the name suggests)
     */
    public void startDocument() {
        // Use accumulator to remember information parsed. Just initialize for
        // now.
        accumulator = new StringBuffer();
    }

    /**
     * Called when the parsing of an element starts. (e.g., <book>)
     * 
     * Lookup documentation to learn meanings of parameters.
     */
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {
        accumulator.setLength(0);
    }

    /**
     * Called for values of elements
     * 
     * Lookup documentation to learn meanings of parameters.
     */
    public void characters(char[] temp, int start, int length) {
        // Remember the value parsed
        accumulator.append(temp, start, length);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the end of an element is seen. (e.g., </title>)
     * 
     * Lookup documentation to learn meanings of parameters.
     * 
     * @throws SAXException
     */
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.toLowerCase().equals("id") || qName.toLowerCase().equals("thetext") ) {
            xmlFile.append(accumulator.toString().trim().toLowerCase());
        }

        // Reset the accumulator because we have seen the value
        accumulator.setLength(0);
    }
}
```

Here I set an accumulator that collects strings as it visits XML tags. Then When I get to an ending tag I set the ID. I am not sure how your XML is setup but this is one way to parse an XML and use it in JAVA.